# Return both string and integer from a template function in C++

Tags: c++, templates, if-statement

I am trying to write a generic function, using template, that is able to return bool, integer or char* or string.

```
template<typename entryType>
entryType getEntry(xml_node node, const char* entryKey)
{
    ...

    if (is_same<entryType, bool>::value) {
         return boolvalue; //returning a boolean
    }
    else if(is_same<entryType, int>::value) {
         return a; //this is an integer
    }
    else if (is_same<entryType, char*>::value) {
         return result; //this is a char*
    }
}
```

and I would like to be able to call it like:

```
bool bPublisher = getEntry<bool>(node, "Publisher");
int QoS = getEntry<int>(node, "QualityOfService");
char* sBrokerUrl = getEntry<char*>(node, "BrokerUrl");
```

as an alternative for the char*, a string would be also fine:

```
string sBrokerUrl = getEntry<string>(node, "BrokerUrl");
```

I get errors like: "cannot convert from 'bool' to 'char*'. I understand the problem, the compiler is not able to detect that the code execution branch depends on the type I give. I just can't find a solution for that. Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Well, you cannot do that with a normal `if`-statement.

Comment: You can't depend the return type on a runtime if statement

Comment: you need to specialize your template. After all, once it gets compiled the tempalte becomes an ordinary function with a well defined return type

Comment: You may use [constexpr if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If C++17 is not available to you, template specialization would probably do what you want:

```
template<typename entryType>
entryType getEntry(xml_node node, const char* entryKey) {}

template<>
bool getEntry<bool>(xml_node node, const char* entryKey) {
   return true;
}

template<>
int getEntry<int>(xml_node node, const char* entryKey) {
   return 1;
}
```

You could put any shared code in a helper function called from each specialization:

```
void shared_code(xml_node node, const char* entryKey) {
   // ...
}

template<>
bool getEntry<bool>(xml_node node, const char* entryKey) {
   shared_code(node, entryKey);
   return true;
}

template<>
int getEntry<int>(xml_node node, const char* entryKey) {
   shared_code(node, entryKey);
   return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since C++17 you can use [constexpr if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If); whose condition part will be evaluated at the compile time, and if the result is `true` then the statement-false part (otherwise the statement-true part) will be discarded. (Thus won't cause the error.) e.g.

```
if constexpr (is_same<entryType, bool>::value) {
     return boolvalue; //returning a boolean
}
else if constexpr (is_same<entryType, int>::value) {
     return a; //this is an integer
}
else if constexpr (is_same<entryType, char*>::value) {
     return result; //this is a char*
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GaJKnx5DSFO0P0G0)

Comment: I was about to post this :|

Comment: @P0W all about the FGITW

Comment: C++17 solutions pretty much useless in real life for the next 10 years

Comment: @lightnessracesinorbit So C++11 solutions will be useful in 2021?

Comment: @RickAstley: One can hope! Real world industry moves very slowly as it relies on stability, safety and security. You don't change technologies unless you need to, because someone might consequently die for no good reason.

Comment: Yes, it looks to be a good and straightforward solution, unfortunately I'm using vs2015.

Comment: @IstvanKadar Then you could use template specilization with a common function. (Or change to a compiler supporting C++17 :) )

Answer (score 2):

For older versions of C++, you can solve this by forwarding to one of the overloaded functions that return result through argument passed by reference:

```
template<typename entryType>
entryType getEntry(xml_node node, const char* entryKey)
{
    entryType result = entryType();
    this->getEntry(node, entryKey, result);
    return result;
}

void getEntry(xml_node node, const char* entryKey, bool& result);
void getEntry(xml_node node, const char* entryKey, int& result);
void getEntry(xml_node node, const char* entryKey, char const *& result);
```

Or you can use `std::enable_if` (since C++11):

```
template<typename entryType>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<entryType, bool>::value, entryType>::type
    getEntry(xml_node node, const char* entryKey) {
    ...
}
```

But first solution, IMO, is more readable. You can make overloaded functions private, if you don't want to expose them.

Answer (score 1):

Like @tobi303 said in the comment, you should specialize the template.
There is no need for fancy SFINAE or other tricks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename entryType>
entryType getEntry(const char* entryKey);

template <>
int getEntry<int>(const char* entryKey)
{
    return 1;
}
template <>
bool getEntry<bool>(const char* entryKey)
{
    return false;
}
template <>
string getEntry<string>(const char* entryKey)
{
    return "asd";
}

int main() {
    bool bPublisher = getEntry<bool>("Publisher");
    int QoS = getEntry<int>("QualityOfService");
    string sBrokerUrl = getEntry<string>("BrokerUrl");

    cout << bPublisher << '\n' << QoS << '\n'<< sBrokerUrl << '\n';
}
```

DEMO: https://wandbox.org/permlink/kyLuPyblb4zBi9fE

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd be inclined to leverage the already-excellent functionality of `std::tuple`.

Combine that with tagged values and it's possible to produce expressive, type-safe code for this kind of thing with minimal effort.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>


template<class Tag, class Type>
struct xmlvalue : Type
{
    using Type::Type;
};

template<class Tag> struct xmlvalue<Tag, bool>
{
    xmlvalue(bool v) : value_(v) {}

    operator bool&() { return value_; }
    operator bool const&() const { return value_; }

private:
    bool value_;
};

template<class Tag> struct xmlvalue<Tag, int>
{
    xmlvalue(int v) : value_(v) {}

    operator int&() { return value_; }
    operator int const&() const { return value_; }

private:
    int value_;
};

struct is_publisher_tag {};
struct qos_tag {};
struct broker_url_tag {};

using is_publisher = xmlvalue<is_publisher_tag, bool>;
using qos = xmlvalue<qos_tag, int>;
using broker_url = xmlvalue<broker_url_tag, std::string>;


struct quote : std::tuple<is_publisher , qos, broker_url >
{
    using std::tuple<is_publisher , qos, broker_url >::tuple;
};

int main() {

    auto q1 = quote(true, 100, "http:://foo.com");
    auto q2 = quote(false, 50, "http:://bar.com");

    std::cout << std::get<broker_url>(q1) << ", " << std::get<qos>(q1) << ", " << std::get<is_publisher>(q1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<broker_url>(q2) << ", " << std::get<qos>(q2) << ", " << std::get<is_publisher>(q2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
http:://foo.com, 100, 1
http:://bar.com, 50, 0
```